# Rails 4 - Best practices - How to display a view with data from different controllers?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building a Rails 4 application.

The application serves to document network hardware devices for a bunch of clients (an app an IT consulting business would use).  The first index view is one that lists all the clients.  At that point, you can click on a link to view items specific to that client.  I've built out different models and controllers for the different types of things I'm documenting (i.e. servers controller, firewall controller, etc.).

I've gotten to the point with nesting where I can get the link from the client index page to pass along the `client.id` and view items associated with that client on that SPECIFIC controller (i.e. it will list all the servers for that client).  Now when you are there I want it to also list all the other items that are from different **models/controllers** as well.  I want one page that displays data from the different **models/controllers**.

I'm trying to determine what the best practice is for a scenario like this.  I feel like I'm missing the obvious and that Rails deals with this in some specific way - or - that most people say Rails sucks/does not do this and everyone does X to accomplish this task.

**Here are the ideas I have in no particular order:**

1. Use partials - seems out of place as partials as I understand are to simplify your view code
2. Render - concern here is how you pass the ID to get the correct client
3. Nesting/Use before action in the controller to set the `client.id` and then write index actions with instance variables for all the other controllers. Already doing this for the nesting and it works, but just for the original request link that contained the `client.id`.  I can't figure out how to pass the `client.id` to the other instance variables so the correct data is displayed.  I feel like I could fix this bug but it seems like I'm going down the wrong path.
4. **JavaScrip/AJAX** type of solution to really make dynamic content happen??

I want to make sure I'm doing this in the good ole fashioned DRY sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are describing is something like a dashboard. There's no single "best" way to handle this, but here is what I would do.

Your controller should define the objects that you will be using in your views. Right now I suspect that you're using something like `servers_controller.rb` which is only defining `@servers`. If your view needs other models, just define them in your action. Let's say you need to list firewalls in addition to servers. Go ahead and add `@firewalls = Firewall.where(client_id: client_id)` or something along those lines. Just make sure you don't start adding business logic to your controller.

Once you have your additional variables defined, you can access them in your views. If you want to be DRY about it, you can create a directory for your dashboard partials (assuming you plan on reusing the same views elsewhere). Then you can use `<%= render "dashboard/firewalls", firewalls: @firewalls %>` to render that partial and pass it to your @firewall variable.

That's just one idea based on what you provided about your setup.

Comment: Exactly, a dashboard.  Thank you very much.  Here's my follow up question, I have avoided using the term "simple rails app" but other than CRUD the benefit of my application is from the simplicity of the UI/UX side of things. I.e. IT field engineers are notorious for not documenting stuff. The other controllers seem a little useless to me right now if all of the items are going to be listed under one controller.    

I know I am asking you to go out on a limb here but what business logic typically would fall outside of that?

Comment: I got really caught up in the exact same issue a couple years ago. I expect that you still need to drill down to a single server, or a single firewall, or a single network. If that's the case, you'll probably still need many of your CRUD controllers. If you think something is pointless, though, don't try to justify keeping it around.

Comment: Your controller actions shouldn't contain a bunch of logic for saving/loading data, they should be calling something else to handle that (maybe a service object). This way you can have different controllers saving similar data while still staying DRY. You will spend a great deal of time trying to find the right solution, and you probably be fully satisfied until you've done it over and over again. Consider looking into the presenter pattern, don't use them unless you really feel like they will help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets list some basics first, No matter if you have only one page contains everything or multipages it depends on the user experience and the logic you gonna implement.

**Your flow is**

- index action to list clients

  **controller**: clients_controller, **action**: index
- index items , servers or whatever

  **controller**: items_controller, **action**: index passing the client_id with the link

ex:

```
link_to client.name, items_path(client_id: client.id) // this will pass params[:client_id] to the action you are requesting and you can add more if you want.
```

- Use **before_action** to do things before starting the execution of your action or to force common behaviour to a bunch of actions to avoid repeating your code and make it readable.
- **Ajax and Jquery** will help you changing any part of the page after the server response so you can create divs and give it unique id ex "#{params[:client_id]}_items_div" and in your response partial **.js** use **$("#DIV_ID").html("YOUR RESPONSE DATA OR RENDER PARTIAL")**.
- Keep your files in their corresponding folders, if you have a partial that lists servers put it under views/servers/index.html.haml or with any extension. This will help you find what you want quickly and help others too.

There are many ways to do what you are looking for but follow the conventions to help others while working on your project.